# how to convert string like '[ ]' to array using python

Tags: python, anaconda

In my data frame,one of column has string values as array look.I get them and stored in an array.Then array look like,

```
S=['[18831]', '[12329]', '[4526, 5101, 11276]', '[14388, 14389]']
```

I want it to be

```
S= [18831,12329,[4526, 5101, 11276],[14388, 14389]]
```

as 2d array to access this IDs.How to do this using python

Comment: Why are the first two no longer going to be lists, but the remaining ones are? What is the logic behind this transformation?

Comment: Those all are IDs.For my research, training model only can be have this look.But, further using testing data, S[0] =[18831,19982]  can be like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lists are in JSON format so you could use the built in JSON parser.

```
import json
stringArray = "[1,2,3]"
integerArray = json.loads(stringArray) # [1,2,3]
```

Check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[eval(a)[0] if len(eval(a)) == 1 else eval(a) for a in S]
```

Comment: eval should never be the answer. Based on your alternative of providing an answer that isn't using the json module, then you should suggest using `literal_eval` instead.

Comment: can you provide example on how to use this literal_eval? because I used this in early but I got an error